# /bin/bash: ./darknet: Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, object-detection, roboflow

I've created an object detection model using [Roboflow's](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mzL6WyY9BRx4xX476eQdhKDnd_eixBlG#scrollTo=NjKzw2TvZrOQ) tutorial and have all the saved weights. The one problem I have is deploying it in a Google Colaboratory. I've changed up some code, but it does not seem to work. So in short, model's trained.

How do I use the model in another Google Colaboratory? I've downloaded the whole darknet folder to the environment with a direct download, some plotting functions and then ran:

and then

```
!./darknet detect cfg/custom-yolov4-detector.cfg backup/custom-yolov4-detector_last.weights {img} #-dont-show
```

Only to get:

/bin/bash: ./darknet: Permission denied

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is darknet executable? Try running `chmod a+x darknet` from the directory containing the file "darknet". Note: this will make the file executable to all users. If you only want the owning user or group to be able to execute the file, supply the relevant arguments to `chmod`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this before your command:
`!chmod +x ./darknet`

Comment: As there is a slight difference with other answer given you need to provide more context to improve its quality.

Comment: There is a small hack in my case , first run !chmod +x ./darknet . now it will show error but now delete !chmod +x and run as normal again  !./darknet

Answer (score 2):

In step 4 of this [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lTGZsfMaGUpBG4inDIQwIJVW476ibXk_#scrollTo=jAN2TNZ007c_) you will find the command **!chmod +x ./darknet**. Depending on your directory, you may need to run **!chmod +x ./darknet/darknet**. It depends on your folder structure. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

need to re-run the darknet !make file

```
%cd /your_path/
!sed -i 's/OPENCV=0/OPENCV=1/g' Makefile
!sed -i 's/GPU=0/GPU=1/g' Makefile
!sed -i 's/CUDNN=0/CUDNN=1/g' Makefile
!sed -i "s/ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60/ARCH= ${ARCH_VALUE}/g" Makefile
!make
```

Answer (score 1):

you are lacking execution permission for that script, you need to do  `chmod +x darknet`

Answer (score 1):

If your files are already compiled using `!make` command, then use `!chmod +x ./darknet/darknet` or else first compile it and then use `!chmod +x ./darknet/darknet`

If it still doesn't work, delete the entire darknet package and then clone it again.

Answer (score 0):

compile the darknet using the make function

```
!make
```

and don't forget to change the makefile

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=1
OPENCV=1
```